# Java, ООП, Модель гоночной трассы

Tags: java, ооп

Хочу спроектировать модель гоночной трассы на Java. Для этого создано несколько простых объектов: `Track`, `Tires`, `Motor`, `Battery`. Которые в свою очередь являются составляющими объекта `Car`.

Проблема затаилась в подсчетах, а именно:
нужно написать метод `buildCar(Track track, Tires tires[], Motor motors[], Battery batteries[])` в классе `Car`, который будет принимать массивы объектов частей и подсчитывать оптимальную конфигурацию автомобиля. Т.е. выбирать части авто таким образом, что бы можно было проехать больше с меньшим расходом батареи.

Для подсчетов есть формулы:

```
calculateConsumption()
            result = this.motor.getPower() * (this.tires.getWeight() + this.motor.getWeight() + this.battery.getWeight()) / 100;
calculateSpeed()
            result = this.tires.getDiameter() * this.motor.getPower() * 1000 / ((this.tires.getWeight() + this.motor.getWeight() + this.battery.getWeight()));
```

А вот и сами Классы:

```
public class Tires
{
    /* 
    * Attributes
    * */

    private double weight;
    private double diameter;

    /* 
    * Constructor's
    * */
    // create new example of an object Tires(set's value for diameter and weight on 0 automatically)
    public Tires(){
        this(0d, 0d);
    }

    // create new example of an object Tires
    public Tires(double weight, double diameter){
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.weight = weight;

    }
```

.

```
public class Motor
{
    /* 
    * Attributes
    * */

    private double weight;
    private double power;


    /* 
    * Constructor's
    * */
    // create new example of an object Motor(set's value for power and weight on 0 automatically)
    public Motor(){
        this(0d, 0d);
    }

    // create new example of an object Motor
    public Motor(double weight, double power){
        this.power = power;
        this.weight = weight;

    }
```

.

```
public class Battery
{
    /* 
    * Attributes
    * */

    private double capacity;
    private double weight;


    /* 
    * Constructor's
    * */
    // create new example of an object Battery(set's value for capacity and weight on 0 automatically)
    public Battery(){
        this(0d, 0d);
    }

    // create new example of an object Battery
    public Battery(double capacity, double weight){
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.weight = weight;
    }


    public boolean reduceCapacity(double n){
        if(this.capacity - n < 0){
            this.capacity -= n;
            return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

А вот и сам класс, в котором нужен метод buildCar

```
public class Car
{
    /* 
    * Attributes
    * */

    private String name;
    private Tires tires;
    private Motor motor;
    private Battery battery;

    /* 
    * Constructor's
    * */
    // create new example of an object Car(set only name of a car)
    public Car(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    // create new example of an object Car
    public Car(String name, Tires tires, Motor motor, Battery battery){
        this.name = name;
        this.tires = tires;
        this.motor = motor;
        this.battery = battery;
    }

    // return true if a car has motor, tires and battery. Battery must not be empty  
    public boolean isFunctional(){
        if (this.motor == null || this.tires == null || this.battery == null){
            return false;
        }
        if (this.battery.getCapacity() <= 0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public double calculateSpeed(){
        double result;
        result = this.tires.getDiameter() * this.motor.getPower() * 1000 / ((this.tires.getWeight() + this.motor.getWeight() + this.battery.getWeight()));
        return result;
    }

    public double calculateConsumption(){
        double result;
        result = this.motor.getPower() * (this.tires.getWeight() + this.motor.getWeight() + this.battery.getWeight()) / 100;
        return result;
    }

    public double raceStep(){
        double result;
        if(this.battery.reduceCapacity(this.calculateConsumption())){
            this.calculateSpeed();
            result = this.calculateSpeed();
            return result;
        }
        else return 0;
    }

    public void buildCar(Track track, Tires tires[], Motor motors[], Battery batteries[] ){

        ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

        }
    }
```

Спасибо большое за любые советы и наводки!!!

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то? Если хотите получить код ревью, то для этого есть отдельный проект. Что за проблема в расчетах и почему вы думаете что проблема вообще есть?

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin, какой проект?

Comment: @Nikolay, ваш вопрос о дизайне классов или о задаче максимизации скорости и минимизации потребления при допустимых значениях параметров?

Comment: @Nofate Моя ошибка, я некорректно задал вопрос. Мне нужно написать метод buildCar(Track track, Tires tires[], Motor motors[], Battery batteries[]) который будет создавать экземпляр объекта класса Car с найлучшими компонентами(Motor, Tires, Battery). Т.е. найти такое соотношение трех компонентов, что бы автомобиль быстрее всего проехал дистанцию(В Классе Track лежит переменная distance). А подсчеты скорости и потребления это calculateSpeed() и calculateConsumption().

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin Моя ошибка. Некорректно сформировал вопрос. В комментарии выше я постарался более точно изложить суть вопроса. А что за проект?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com - для код ревью, он, конечно, на английском, но отправить код на речью можно с любым уровнем английского, код он везде одинаковый...

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin, в этом нет нужды, код-ревью разрешены у нас, см. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько я понял, метод `calculateSpeed()` считает не скорость, а расстояние пройденное за единицу времени. Если так, то погнали дальше =)

Для удобства я буду писать логику сокращая всякие ненужности. Вместо `this.motor.getPower()` буду писать `motor.power`.

Сначала вычислим какую батарею нам взять:

Вычисления скорости:

```
tires.diameter * motor.power * 1000 / (tires.weight + motor.weight + battery.weight)
```

Вычисления потребления:

```
motor.power * (tires.weight + motor.weight + battery.weight) / 100
```

Нам нужно получить наибольшую скорость при наименьшем потреблении. Так как мы рассчитываем только батарею, то можем смело откинуть остальные параметры и получим:

Скорость (расстояние за единицу времени): `speed = 1000 / battery.weight`

Потребление: `consumption = battery.weight / 100`

Теперь посчитаем, сколько шагов сможет пройти автомобиль при объеме конкретной батареи:

```
steps = battery.capacity / consumption
```

Далее округляем `steps` в меньшую сторону и умножаем на `speed`. Таким образом мы получим расстояние которое сможет проехать машина с определенной батареей без учета остальных факторов. В цикле по массиву батарей пробегаемся и делаем вычисления, запоминаем индекс с самым большим расстоянием и используем батарею которая лежит в массиве под этим индексом.

Я постарался не решить полностью задачу за тебя, а показать как это делается, так что остальное придется вывести самому =)

P.S. Не нужно усложнять код лишними бессмысленными строками. Функцию `calculateSpeed()`, которая сейчас выглядит так:

```
public double calculateSpeed(){
    double result;
    result = this.tires.getDiameter() * this.motor.getPower() * 1000 / ((this.tires.getWeight() + this.motor.getWeight() + this.battery.getWeight()));
    return result;
}
```

в данном случае можно и нужно записывать так:

```
public double calculateSpeed() {
    return this.tires.getDiameter() * this.motor.getPower() * 1000 / ((this.tires.getWeight() + this.motor.getWeight() + this.battery.getWeight()));
}
```

так как твой вариант менее читабельный, каждый раз смотря на функцию обращаешь внимание на эти строчки и пытаешься понять делают ли они что-то важное или нет.

Удачи! Надеюсь тебе поможет мой ответ =)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все получилось.

Comment: Не за что, самому интересно было =)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал применить паттерн Builder. То есть создавать машину не в самом классе `Car`, а создать отдельный класс `CarBuilder`, который будет создавать машину, исходя из переданных параметров.